# Using different database users with GORM

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm

I´m working on a grails 1.3.7 application, which, by design, the client wants to keep all the users at a database level, so he can leverage his database's features regarding login, permissions, etc. (Database is Oracle 10g).

Is there a way I can configure GORM to use a different user/pass to connect to the database when the user logs in? Something like build a user/pass form and pass those credentials to GORM to connect to the database?

What would be the best practice to implement this scenario?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you are going to be killing the ability of the servlet engine to pool datasources.  Performance is going to suffer, because each and every request is going to require a new, dedicated connection.  There's a lot of overhead in that.  If at all possible, I'd really be re-thinking or arguing against that design.

Comment: That's true, i do not really agree with that design... But as i said you can  just open a connection and keep it, for every logged in user... It helps but won't work fine if you have a thousand users... Btw why -1 for my reply? please at least comment if you do not agree...

Comment: Thanks guys, I also agree the design should be reconsidered. But I've seen a design like this before, so I'm just trying to see how it could be implemented, so I can negotiate with an explanation other than "this design sucks"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know grails but it uses Hibernate.

What i think:

You use the session factory to interact with the database, and each session factory has a datasource, which has the url of the db and le l/p.

So what you need is to have one session factory for each user so that you can connect to the DB with different authentification. I don't see any simpler solution.

This means that you kinda need the same requirements multi tenancy applications using multiple databases/schemas have. Except you do not use different databases/schemas but just different l/p.

It seems you are looking for the Multi tenant plugin, in the "single tenant mode":
http://www.grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant

> **Single-Tenant Mode** 
>   Converts the "dataSource" bean into an AOP proxy
>   that creates a new datasource for each tenant

(finally i was wrong, you can use a single session factory and a "dynamic datasource" ^^)

**Edit:**

http://grails.org/Multi-Tenant+Plugin+-+Single+Tenant+Database+Set+Up

> The single-tenant option is a little more immature than the
>   multi-tenant option. It inherits all datasource configuration from the
>   default datasource in Datasource.groovy, and allows you to provide a
>   custom datasource url per tenant. **This means that you can't mix and
>   match drivers or user/pass combos for different tenants in the same
>   instance.**

It seems that finally you can't do that with the plugin, only change the url... As they say it's a little immature but you perhaps can contribute to that plugin so that it becomes possible to also change the user/password, or just check how they did that and develop your own plugin...

...Or perhaps someone already developped that...

**Edit2:**

What you can also do is:

1) Everytime a user log in, create a new datasource using the user l/p and add it to a pool of datasources (map)
(When he logs out or session expire, remove that datasource)

2) When you get a request from a user, put the id of this user in a threadlocal (with a filter for exemple).

3) Create a new datasource implementation MultiAuthentificationDatasourceImpl in which you will inject the datasource pool, and map all the methods to the database you should use. For exemple, your getConnection() method will be:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    return getDatasourceToUse().getConnection();
}

public Datasource getDatasourceToUse() {
   return datasourcePool.get( getUserIdFromThreadLocal() );
}
```

And almost the same for all methods, you can reuse the getDatasourceToUse() method...

4) Use that MultiAuthentificationDatasourceImpl as your datasource in grails config

But i don't know grails, just it is possible in Java...

Comment: Thanks for looking a possible solution, I'll be using your answer to try yo implement this for Grails, but finally I think I'll just negotiate with the client about the disadvantages of this design for the application. BTW I didn't -1 your reply, not sure who was, I did find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (if you have only one database for your application and want to use the database users managed by the DBMS only for authentication).

You could use a specific user for the global access to the database and write an authentication scheme that authenticate users by creating a new Connection to the database with their own user name and password.

So, in this situation you'll have to advantages:

- A single database (you don't need to have one SessionFactory per user, which whould eventually DESTROY your application)
- All the users will be managed by the DBMS, and not by your application

Comment: No, this would not give them what their looking for: having a log for each user's operations and being able to manage permissions for the different operations in the DB. The requirement goes beyond authentication only.